# Can't register category taxonomy to a custom post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Well, i'm trying to register the default taxonomy "category" to some custom posts in wordpress...

The field "categories" are working but when i go to "/category/cat_name" i get an empty array for posts with that category. But if i use the same category on a regular post, it works perfectly.

The solution that i read in every site is: `register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'custom-type');`, and of course i tryied it... nothing happens.

Look at my `funcions.php`:

This is my `register_post_types()` for take all post type registered:

```
function register_post_types() {
    register_post_type( 'articulos',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Tiendas' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Tienda' )
                    ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),
                'taxonomies' => array('category')
                )
            );

        register_post_type( 'locacion',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Arriendos' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Arriendo' )
                    ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' =>  true,
                'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),
                'taxonomies' => array('category')
                )
            );
}
```

As you can see, the taxonomies are enabled, then, i register them:

```
function register_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'articulos');
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'locacion');
}
```

And **after** i hooked all in their `init`:

```
function __construct() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats' );
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_theme_support( 'menus' );
    add_filter( 'timber_context', array( $this, 'add_to_context' ) );
    add_filter( 'get_twig', array( $this, 'add_to_twig' ) );
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_types' ) );
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_taxonomies' ) );
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Ignore all above from `add_action`... in all cases the problem is the same, custom posts marked with any category are not listed in the respective link.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!!

**Edit**

My `archive.php` file look like this:

```
$templates = array( 'archive.twig', 'index.twig' );

$data = Timber::get_context();

$data['title'] = 'Archive';
if ( is_day() ) {
    $data['title'] = 'Archive: '.get_the_date( 'D M Y' );
} else if ( is_month() ) {
    $data['title'] = 'Archive: '.get_the_date( 'M Y' );
} else if ( is_year() ) {
    $data['title'] = 'Archive: '.get_the_date( 'Y' );
} else if ( is_tag() ) {
    $data['title'] = single_tag_title( '', false );
} else if ( is_category() ) {
    $data['title'] = single_cat_title( '', false );
    array_unshift( $templates, 'archive-' . get_query_var( 'cat' ) . '.twig' );
} else if ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
    $data['title'] = post_type_archive_title( '', false );
    array_unshift( $templates, 'archive-' . get_post_type() . '.twig' );
}

$data['posts'] = Timber::get_posts();

Timber::render( $templates, $data );
```

Now, i post this in response to a question:

> Have you set post_type in your query? Default query shows only standard posts

But as i know, with this is not necessary...

PD: i'm using [timber](http://jarednova.github.io/timber/) plugin for wordpress, this is for render twig files

Comment: Have you set post_type in your query? Default query shows only standard post.

Comment: Hey @Piotr i updated the post with the archive.php, im not a php developer so i really don't know a bunch a lot of thinks. Of course i know what the hell do that archive, but as i know the get_posts(); get all posts related at the query.

Comment: All posts but not Custom Post Types. Could you insert your query code?

Comment: The `Timber::get_posts();` is the query code, i can pass it `Timber::get_posts("post_type=''post-type");` and it returns me all of those posts, but just them, i'll try something, just an idea.

Comment: You can pass array to post_type or set its value to 'any', more on this subject you'll find here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters

Comment: It works! But partially. It's a weird thing because all articles have all categories, no matter if i uncheck the categories, they are still listed! Here is the query: ```$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post', 'locacion', 'articulos')
);

$data['posts'] = Timber::get_posts($args);```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96421/discussion-between-nano-and-piotr).

Comment: It's because you overwrite default $args, please try this:
`global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'post_type' => array('post', 'locacion', 'articulos') );` this should do the work

Comment: Well, nope, now the template is missing, so when i go to the link the body is empty. This is really weird, and i don't want to keep bothering you or make this an infinite post :/